# Lua: getglobal inside callback

Tags: c, lua

I'm trying to understand the Lua-C-API.  To this end I have written a simple callback which attempts to get a global variable, prints its arguments, and pushes two return values.  I saved the Lua code I want to run as `test.lua`.  It is very simple and reads

```lua
var = 134
local n,s = callback(3.14, _VERSION)
print(n,s)
```

The **expected output** would be

```
global var = 134.000000
arg 1 = 3.14
arg 2 = Lua 5.2
123.456 Hello
```

however, the **actual output** is

```
global var = 3.140000
arg 1 = 3.14
arg 2 = Lua 5.2
arg 3 = 134
123.456 Hello
```

This is a clear indication for me messing with the stack in ways I don't understand.  Below is my compilable C code example.  To compile use

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 test.c -llua
```

Then run the example Lua file `test.lua` using

```
./a.out test.lua
```

Can you help me get the stack right?

---

```c
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

static int l_callback(lua_State* L)
{
  lua_getglobal(L, "var");
  double var = NAN;
  if (lua_isnumber(L, 1))
    var = lua_tonumber(L, 1);
  printf("global var = %f\n", var);

  int args = lua_gettop(L);
  for (int n = 1; n <= args; ++n)
    printf("arg %d = %s\n", n, lua_tostring(L, n));
  lua_pushnumber(L, 123.456);
  lua_pushstring(L, "Hello");

  return 2;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if (argc <= 1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <lua file>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_openlibs(L);

  lua_register(L, "callback", l_callback);

  if (luaL_dofile(L, argv[1]) != LUA_OK)
  {
    const char* message = lua_tostring(L, -1);
    puts(message);
    lua_pop(L, 1);
  }

  lua_close(L);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`3.14` and `_VERSION` are already pushed into stack, so calling `lua_getglobal` for `var` its index will be `3`.

You can adjust the code using displacement index, to grant to pop the value of last pushed var value into stack.

```
  lua_getglobal(L, "var");
  double var = NAN;
  if (lua_isnumber(L, -1))
    var = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
  printf("global var = %f\n", var);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I didn't know you could use displacement indices on the stack.  Also, one has to `lua_pop(L,1);` after this part.  Otherwise the global `var` will stay on the stack and will be counted as an argument.